# Assignment of property if not null, possible with null-coalecing?

Tags: c#, linq, null-coalescing-operator

I'm trying to do smth like

Im trying to assign property on an object if this object is not null.
but standard form of non-null invocation does not work for assignment like this

```
socket?.Blocking = false
```

what I'm trying to do is shorten this if possible:

```
if(socket != null) socket.Blocking = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a great feature

```
b?.c = "bob"
```

Though, it's flawed when it comes to compound assignments. Consider this

```
a.b?.c = "bob"
```

What should it do on `null`?

Personally, I think it should just ignore the parents. But alas, *the powers that be* have *probably* made the right decision to disallow this because of inconsistency with the other use cases of *null conditional*.

Note : you could roll your own an extension method, though it's not very satisfying, and would probably fail my code reviews just on abstractness and readability.

```
a?b.NullConditional(x => x.c = "bob");
```

You are left with

```
if(a?.b != null) a.b.c = "bob"
```

or in your case

```
if(socket != null) socket.Blocking = false
```

or to write a dedicated extension method for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way would be to use an extension method, so you could write:

```
socket?.SetBlocking(false);
```

You can create the extension method like this:

```
public static class SocketExtensions
{
    public static void SetBlocking(this Socket socket, bool blocking)
    {
        if (socket != null) socket.Blocking = blocking;
    }
}
```

Comment: To bad .net core sockets dont have built-in setBlocking()... i guess this cannot be shortened then